# How to change the default naming style of component instances in PowerDesigner 15.x?

Tags: powerdesigner

By default, when dragging existing components into different PowerDesigner models (e.g. deployment), the component instance is named as ComponentInstance_X where X is an incremental counter. How can I change this naming style to something different such as ComponentType::X?

I use version 15.1 of PowerDesigner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a complete answer (and I've just verified part of it with 15.2 but...)

You could create/attach an extension to your model, with an event handler "Initialize" on the ComponentInstance metaclass.

This event handler would allow you to modify the name/code of the instance as it is created...